# How to identify the color of candle?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

i want to put a  long position when at least 3 candles are red and the next one formed after it should be green or if the red candle is still forming, i want to wait until a green candle shows up

```
if open[3] > open[2] and open[2] > open[1] // here i want to check if red candles are still forming  after these 3
   if open >= open[1]  //  here I want to check if the current candle is green or not 
      strategy.entry("long", strategy.long,100)
```

i don't have much idea how can i form this condition so i am unable to provide more than this ,

[image: reference to my idea]

Comment: How do you define "red" or "green" candle? Usually if the current bar `close` price is above current bar `open` price, then it's green and vice versa, but from your code example I understand you're defining "red" candles as when current candle `open` price is lower then previous candle `open` price?

Answer (score 0):

As we can understand from your image, red candle is a beaish candle, green is a bullish candle.
In your code you can use :

```
red_candle = close < open
green_candle = open > close

// here i want to check if red candles are still forming  after these 3
if red_candle[3] and red_candle[2] and red_candle[1]
    //  here I want to check if the current candle is green or not 
    if green_candle
        strategy.entry("long", strategy.long,100)
```

Comment: hi, I tried your solution it works great but sometimes it is taking long positions on red candles instead of green.                                                                                                       
             ` if red_candle[3] and red_candle[2] and red_candle[1] 
                    if green_candle      
                       strategy.entry("long", strategy.long,100)`

Comment: Pinescript evaluate the code each time the price or volume change. Perhaps during the candle formation, it was green... so your code took the trade... and at the end the candle change to red. If you do not want calculation during the candle formation, you shoudl use barstate.isconfirmed (see https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_barstate{dot}isconfirmed)